# MonkeyTalk boolean logic

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-testing

I'm trying to write scripts in JavaScripts to test the UI of an iPhone app with MonkeyTalk. How do I use logic and conditionals with this? Right now I have a block:

```
if (this.app.button("name").verify())
      do this if button exists
```

The problem is verify doesn't return a bool, it just throws an error in the test if the button doesn't exist. Is there a way to catch the error and run a script accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work :

```
function verifiedViewOrNull (view)
{
var exists = false;
try
{
    view.verify();
    exists = true;
}
catch (e)
{

}

return exists ? view : null;
}
```

and you can just call it as such :

```
if (verifiedViewOrNull(this.app.view("name")) != null
{
      // It exists
} else
      //doesn't exist, not gonna throw exception
```